# android use Google Maps API in an existing app

Tags: android

I have developed an app and now I want to add new activity to show Google Maps using API.

So how can I use google maps API V2 in existing app in new activity?

Please reply.Thanks.

Comment: you can easily find that on google. try to search it! https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Answer (score 0):

You can start a new project in Android Studio and specify a Google Map project and see how it's implemented then work your code into that existing code or just pick out the parts you need for your current project.
Also, as Silvuz mentioned, check out the documentation! 
[developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android](http://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android)